# Warden authentication is failing when I use failure app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, warden

I am having trouble authenticating using Warden (Warden only, without Devise) when I use the failure app.

This error does not happen when I use Warden configured not to use the failure app.

Help me!

My warden.rb **config/initializers/warden.rb**:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
  manager.failure_app = -> (env) { 
  SessionsController.action(:new).call(env) }
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session do |user|
  user.id
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session do |id|
  User.find(id)
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:password) do
  def authenticate!
    user = User.find_by(email: params['email'])

    if user && user.authenticate(params['password'])
      success! user
    else
      fail 'Invalid email or password'
    end
  end
end
```

My **routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  get 'sessions/new'
  post 'sessions/create'
  get 'sessions/destroy'

  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
end
```

My **SessionsController**:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    flash.now[:alert] = warden.message if warden.message.present?
  end

  def create
    warden.authenticate!
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Logged in!'
  end

  def destroy
    warden.logout
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Logged out!'
  end
end
```

My **ApplicationController**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def current_user
    warden.user
  end

  def warden
    request.env['warden']
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Error screen:

[image]

My **backtrace**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your CSRF authenticity token being invalid -- used twice, once in each controller maybe?

You might have luck adding

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:new]
```

to your `SessionsController`.